# semantic-release no longer updating git notes

Tags: gitlab, semantic-release

Up until around early October 2023, all of our GitLab pipelines were working normally. We've been using semantic release for over a year. But about a month ago, the git notes aren't updating.

This causes the error "cannot create new tag because it exists".

What happens is:

- pipeline runs with semantic-release
- tag is created with new version
- no notes are added (eg: `{ "channels": ["main"]}`)
- next pipeline runs with semantic-release but fails because the prior tag has no notes

is anyone else seeing this? Are there any known issues that would cause this?

In the meanwhile, I'm manually updating `git notes` for every version which is several per day.